# Tests fails with TransactionTestCase and pytest

Tags: python, django, pytest, django-1.8

I have an issue with a my unit tests and the way django manages transactions.

In my code I have a function:

```
def send():
    autocommit = transaction.set_autocommit(False)
    try:
         # stuff
    finally:
         transaction.rollback()
         transaction.set_autocommit(autocommit)
```

In my test I have:

```
class MyTest(TransactionTestCase):
    def test_send(self):
        send()
```

The issue  I am having is that my `test_send` passes successfully but not 80% of my other tests.

It seems the transaction of the other tests are failing

btw I am using py.test to run my tests

EDIT:
To make things more clear when I run my tests with only 
myapp.test.test_module.py it runs fine and all 3 tests passes but when I run all my tests most of the fails, will try to produce a test app

Also all my tests passes with the default test runner from django

EDIT2:
Here is A minimal example to test this issue:

```
class ManagementTestCase(TransactionTestCase):

    def test_transfer_ubl(self, MockExact):
        pass

class TestTestCase(TestCase):

     def test_1_user(self):
         get_user_model().objects.get(username="admin")
         self.assertEqual(get_user_model().objects.all().count(), 1)
```

Bear in mind there is a datamigration that adds an "admin" user (the TestTestCase succeeds alone but not when the ManagmentTestCase is run before)

It seems autocommit has nothing to do with it.

Comment: where does this send() method come from? Please post an example of a test that fails after you have called send()

Comment: I wrote the send method, the other tests are failing because when they count objects in their isolation is broken

Comment: Sorry if my comment isn't clear. Is the send method part of a view? Part of the test code? And please also add a sample of a test that fails when executed together with this one

Comment: Sounds like you've got a dependency between test cases and are relying on the [guaranteed ordering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/overview/#order-in-which-tests-are-executed) that the django runner gives you...  Does py.test work if you reorder as per the django runner?

Comment: @PeterBrittain if I put my transaction test cases as last tests everything is ok but if I use --reuse-db the next time I launch my test they fail

Comment: And is the same true when you re-run tests with the django runner?  If so, I think you are simply not clearing up your DB correctly...  An MCVE would help at that point.

Comment: Isn't `transaction.set_autocommit(False)` returns `None`? What's the reason to set `autocommit = transaction.set_autocommit(False)`?

Answer (score 4):

The [`TestCase`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/tools/#testcase) class wraps the tests inside two atomic blocks. Therefore it is not possible to use `transaction.set_autocommit()` or `transaction.rollback()` if you are inheriting from `TestCase`.

As the docs say, you should use `TransactionTestCase` if you are testing specific database transaction behaviour.

Comment: I did but it breaks most of my other tests

Comment: Split your test class into two classes. Use `TransactionTestCase` for the `test_send` method, and `TestCase` for the others.

Comment: I did that, I have more than 300 tests

Comment: It doesn't matter how many tests you make. It's not possible to use `send()` inside a `TestCase` class.

Answer (score 4):

having `autocommit = transaction.set_autocommit(False)` inside the `send` function feels wrong.  Disabling the transaction is done here presumably for testing purposes, but the rule of thumb is to keep your test logic outside your code.

As @Alasdair has pointed out, [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/transactions/#django-s-default-transaction-behavior) states "Django’s TestCase class also wraps each test in a transaction for performance reasons."

It is not clear from your question whether you're testing specific database transaction logic or not, if that is the case  then @Alasdair's answer of using the `TransactionTestCase` is the way to go.

Otherwise, removing the transaction context switch from around the `stuff` inside your `send` function should help.

Since you mentioned `pytest` as your test runner, I would also recommend making use of pytest.  Pytest-django plugin comes with nice features such selectively setting some of your tests to require transactions, using [markers](http://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html#pytest-mark-django-db-transaction-false-request-database-access).

```
pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=False)
```

If installing a plugin is too much, then you could roll your own `transaction manage` fixture.  Like

```
  @pytest.fixture
  def no_transaction(request):
      autocommit = transaction.set_autocommit(False)
      def rollback():
          transaction.rollback()
          transaction.set_autocommit(True)
      request.addfinalizer(rollback)
```

Your `test_send` will then require the `no_transaction` fixture.

```
def test_send(no_transaction):
    send()
```

Comment: I use autocommit = False  + transaction.rollback because I do not want that some calls inside send() saves a model to db, I want the db to be untouched this has nothing to do with the test logic, I tried to use pytest.mark with no success, will try again

Comment: I did use pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=False) but now it seems the database is emptied during the tests which leads to other errors in the later tests

Comment: you get a completely new clean slated database for each test, if this isn't what you want you can explicitly use ``keepdb`` option from http://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database.html#django-db-keepdb

Answer (score 1):

For those who still looking for a solution, `serialized_rollback` option is a way to go:

```
class ManagementTestCase(TransactionTestCase):
    serialized_rollback = True

    def test_transfer_ubl(self, MockExact):
        pass

class TestTestCase(TestCase):

     def test_1_user(self):
         get_user_model().objects.get(username="admin")
         self.assertEqual(get_user_model().objects.all().count(), 1)
```

from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/overview/#rollback-emulation)

> Django can reload that data for you on a per-testcase basis by setting the `serialized_rollback` option to `True` in the body of the `TestCase` or `TransactionTestCase`, but note that this will slow down that test suite by approximately 3x.

Unfortunately, [pytest-django](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) still missing this feature.

Comment: As of [pytest-django v4.5.0](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html#v4-5-0-2021-12-01) this is now a kwarg to the `django_db` marker.